# How to set width with 2 div's using pixels and percents

Tags: html, css, layout, width

I have this example [here](http://jsbin.com/usopux).

I'd like you to follow these steps:

- resize your browser window to less than 950 pixels wide.
- now scroll to your right with the horizontal scroll-bar.
- now you will notice that the grey bar (div) stops short and does not continue to the right edge of the page.

I want to know how to fix it so the grey bar continues across the whole page.

Comment: @Sparky672 wow , thanks for the editing , it's like 200% more understandable , btw sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-width` on the bar itself with the same width as the content in it...

I don't know what kind of cross browser compatiblity you want but this should work in IE7 > . Any more would make this a lot more complex.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/hrN5F/

Edit, this might solve it for older versions of IE too, can't test it though http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/hrN5F/2/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using css to set your `bgcolor` and `border`, use an image 1px wide and however high you need it to be.

```
`background:url('images/bg.gif') repeat-x;`
```

Be sure to include a 1px bottom border inside your `bg` image.

Comment: it's not solving my problem !

Comment: He's suggesting you should use an image to make the background color in the top happen. Btw an image of just 1px wide repeated infinity times slows down older versions of IE, better to give it some more width, like 10px, IE will not have to repeat it as much and as a result cope much better with the image.

Comment: sg3s, I didn't think of older versions of ie having problems with that but it does make sense. nice point out. curse ie!